# Pasting from system clipboard works bad in "Visual-block" mode?

Tags: gvim, visual-block

For example:

[image]

mode: Visual-block.

In Gvim:

[image]

Now, I want to paste the system clipboard, say "4", to the  position, I tried "p", now it becomes (**that's not what I want!**):

[image]

In Gvim:

[image]

I want:

[image]

I think a lot and tried a lot, no way! Can anyone help me? Thanks!

PS: I know I can input "4" mannualy, but if the content is a long string, copy and paste is more rational obviously

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Please try to share text as text whenever possible. Since you used screenshots, you might as well add one which shows your actual visual selection. I cannot reproduce your problem. BTW, `"+p` pastes from system clipboard.

Comment: Your screenshots don't match your problem description at all. Given your screenshots, the outcome you get is the only possible outcome of what you are doing.

Comment: I don't understand the question. According to your first image, you have spaces between the numbers. But according to the other images, you lost those spaces? That cannot happen during pasting. Also, assuming you have only a single `4` in your clipboard (and in particular no linebreaks). If I use `"+p` while visual-block selecting a single column, that column will be replaced by the 4 and that is the default behaviour.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do: `I`<kbd>Ctrl R</kbd>`+`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Where `+` is the system clipboard. Replace with another register if you want to paste from it.

Or, if you were on Windows `I`<kbd>Ctrl R</kbd>`*`<kbd>Esc</kbd> would also work.

Comment: According to the title, OP wants to post from system clipboard. `I<C-R>+<Esc>` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich, I have modified the solution :-)